# Trying to assign values to keys in dictionary gives type error

Tags: python, dictionary

dict["north-west"]=(south+width_NS,west)

TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, south, west, width_WE, width_NS, height=10):
```

> ```
>       keys=("north-west","north-east","south-west","south-east")
>       dict.fromkeys(keys)
>       dict['north-west']=(south+width_NS,west)
>       dict["north-east"]=(south+width_NS,west+width_WE)
>       dict["south-west"]=(south,west)
>       dict["south-east"]=(south,west+width_WE)
>   self.corners=dict
> ```

Comment: I'd note that using `fromkeys` like this when you're going to set each value afterwards anyway is completely necessary. You could replace `dict.fromkeys(keys)` with `dict = {}` and your code would work (though using `dict` as a variable name is bad style).

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the created dictionary :

```
d = dict.fromkeys(keys)
```

This gives :

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(keys)
>>> d
{'south-west': None, 'south-east': None, 'north-east': None, 'north-west': None}
>>> d['north-west'] = (south+width_NS,west)
{'south-west': None, 'south-east': None, 'north-east': None, 'north-west': (6, 8)}
```

(I used some random values for `south`, `width_NS` and `west`)

Comment: I got it. I used 'dict' as a variable name while clearly I shouldn't as it is already sort of a function.

Comment: @Newbie_programmer you can use `dict` as a name for a variable (which is `d` in my example), but do not mix the variable with the type [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable name, say, dict1. Here is the correct code:

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, south, west, width_WE, width_NS, height=10):
      keys=("north-west","north-east","south-west","south-east")
      dict1 = dict.fromkeys(keys)
      dict1['north-west']=(south+width_NS,west)
      dict1["north-east"]=(south+width_NS,west+width_WE)
      dict1["south-west"]=(south,west)
      dict1["south-east"]=(south,west+width_WE)
      self.corners=dict1
```